# How can I post screenshots with less than 10 reputation?

Tags: support, privileges, images, drafts

I have just spent quite some time putting a decent question together including screenshots and diagrams only to realize I need 10 points to post images in my questions.

How can post the images though?

If there was a way to save it to drafts I would, but I don't think there is one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### What if you can't post images?

These restrictions are in place to prevent spam. If you can't post your image, but already uploaded it to the editor, look for the images the editor automatically embedded for your. It will look like this:

```
![enter image description here][1]
![enter image description here][2]
```

Remove the exclamation marks, and the editor won't treat them as images anymore – they will now be rendered as:

> [enter image description here](http://example.com)
>   [enter image description here](http://example.com)

Replace the description text with "Screenshot 1", "Screenshot 2" or similar and submit the post. Later, if users with enough privileges happen to see your post, they will most likely embed the images for you. Don't worry about not being able to include the images from the beginning on – everybody is used to seeing questions by new users.

#### What if you can't post more than two links?

If you have more than two screenshots, you can remove the links altogether and just paste the URL without `http://`. For example:

```
[link][1]

  [1]: http://example.com
```

Would become:

```
example.com
```

This way, it's not an actual link and you will be able to submit your post. Similarly, once users with edit privileges fix your post, the links will be properly embedded.

But please, think about whether your post really needs more than two screenshots. Too many images will make the post excessively long in scrolling height and will mask the comments and answers – other users might skip reading your question if it seems too long.

Also, note that [once you have 200 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) on any other Stack Exchange site, your accounts on other sites will get a 100 reputation bonus, so embedding images should no longer be an issue.

Comment: TIL I get 100 point bonus once I get over 200! Better give some good answers then, thanks for the info.